# Trying to replace a piece of text without affecting a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, replace

Can someone tell me how to preserve the url in this replace? when i run this code it finds and replaces the text but removes the link [text](http://www.google.com) and just has the word text. I need to preserve the link and this is just a simple example. The actually code I need to work with a a dynamic link so I can just manually replace it.

```js
$(".text_div").text(function () {
  return $(this).text().replace("contains", "hello everyone");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text_div">
  This div contains some <a href="http://www.google.com">text</a>.
</div>
```

this give's me

> This div hello everyone text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.html()` instead of `.text()`:

```
$(".text_div").html(function() {
  return $(this).html().replace("contains", "hello everyone");
})
```

```js
$(".text_div").html(function() {
  return $(this).html().replace("contains", "hello everyone");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text_div">
  This div contains some <a href="http://www.google.com">text</a>.
</div>
```

Comment: then i get This div hello everyone some <a href="http://www.google.com">text</a>. That is was is output, not a link.

Comment: Did you actually try the snippet in my answer? What you're saying is not true. Make sure you change both .text() in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $(this).text(), you should be doing $(this).html().

Comment: What is different your answer with j08691' answer?

Comment: We must be writing it in parallel.